# Stored procedure is not accepting null

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, asp.net-core-mvc

I am executing this stored procedure and it works fine, but when I am calling from the frontend side, it returns no rows.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_GetRequest_DataListForViewPrint]
    @RequestNo VARCHAR(50) = null, 
    @FromDate varchar(50) = null,
    @ToDate varchar(50) = null
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQLStr varchar(8000), @WHERECRI VARCHAR(1000) = NULL

    IF (@RequestNo IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        SET @WHERECRI = 'WHERE RequestNo='+ CHAR(39)+@RequestNo+ CHAR(39) ;
    END 
    ELSE  
    BEGIN
        SET @WHERECRI = ' WHERE RequestDate BETWEEN ' + CHAR(39) + CONVERT(varchar(10), CONVERT(datetime, @FromDate, 105), 102) + CHAR(39) + 'AND' + CHAR(39) + CONVERT(varchar(10), CONVERT(datetime, @ToDate, 105), 102)  + CHAR(39);
    END

    SET @SQLStr = 'SELECT Id, RequestStatus, RequestDate, RequestNo FROM CYGNUX_Request_Header ' + @WHERECRI;
    PRINT @SQLStr;

    EXEC(@SQLStr);
END
```

In the frontend it take parameter this way and this is does not return any data:

```
EXEC  USP_GetRequest_DataListForViewPrint  '', '08-06-2020 00:00:00','16-06-2020 00:00:00'
```

But if I execute this in SQL Server this way it is returning data. I don't know what's wrong in my frontend

```
EXEC  USP_GetRequest_DataListForViewPrint  null, '08-06-2020 00:00:00','16-06-2020 00:00:00'
```

Please help me - how can I solve this?

Comment: (1) Why are you using non-standard date/date time formats?  (2) Why doesn't the stored procedure accept dates?  (3) What is the problem you are encountering?

Comment: Store procedure is working if I test in SQL server but when I call from frontend side(visual studio ) it returns no data over there because it not accepting null value

Comment: `null` is not the same as an empty string. Your frontend version is going to cause the flow of control to set the predicate to `where requestNo = ''`, because an empty string is not null.

Comment: Also, we've seen this procedure across several questions over the last few days. You should adopt some of the other great advice you've been given - like using proper datatypes, eliminating the unnecessary dynamic sql, and so on. Your job will be much easier!

Comment: Show how you "call from frontend side" and what the resulting `print`ed dynamic SQL is.

Answer (score 0):

In the frontend you are not passing NULL but an empty string, therefor your SP is executing the Select with a WHERE on RequestNo equal to an empty string which probably doesn't return any record.

Comment: I am passing null for RequestNo from frontend side

Comment: They have another line where they _do_ pass `null`, and apparently that doesn't work as expected; the SP checks for `null` and is meant to do something else, in this case not return data it seems.

Comment: just be sure to double check that you are passing null from the frontend. You first write { In the frontend it take parameter this way and this is does not return any data:
EXEC  USP_GetRequest_DataListForViewPrint  '', '08-06-2020 00:00:00','16-06-2020 00:00:00' } which uses 2 single quotes as parameter value for RequestNo (which is not null), and then you write { But if I execute this in SQL Server this way it is returning data. I don't know what's wrong in my frontend
EXEC  USP_GetRequest_DataListForViewPrint  null, '08-06-2020 00:00:00','16-06-2020 00:00:00 } This is different

Comment: Can you provide a few more lines of code from your frontend so that we can see what is really passed as values?